# Object which includes another object, and pass itself to it (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a problem which I didn't expect, so I can't just do what I want in another way, because it will affect project structure, I spend a lot of time trying to solve it.

I have a class World and a class Chunk. There's one instance of class World.

In this class I have `std::vector` of Chunks, so it must include Chunk.h.

In class Chunk I have function `Generate()` which must get `World & world`, because it must get variables from other Chunks, get textures and use methods from World class, so Chunks must include World.h.

World is passing itself by `this`  to funtions like `Generate()`.

Both classes have `#pragma once`.

It simply doesn't work and I don't know why. "World" is syntax error.

Thank for any help!

Comment: you can use a forward declaration, however imho such mutual dependencies are better avoided right from the start

Comment: [mcve], please. Your description is rather vague to someone not versed in your code base.

Comment: Thanks! I added `class World;` before definition of Chunk and vice versa, and it works.

Comment: You should write a separate header with those declarations and include them instead of writing new declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As tobi303 mentioned, these circular dependencies should be avoided.

If you want to do it anyway, forward-declaration will hlep you:

*world.h*

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include "chunk.h"

class World
{
  // methods

private:
  std::vector<Chunk> _chunks;
};
```

*chunk.h*

```
#pragma once

class World;

class Chunk
{
public:
  void Generate(World& world);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, in JS (ES6) I did structures like this but there wasn't any problem.

Comment: It's not much of problem in C++,it actually excels at those, but it requires correct formulation. Look up "Curiously recurring template pattern" as an example of recurrent definitions and marvel.